# How Set Local Variable to Specific Value in Result Set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I have this code working:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) AS NumSold, Game.Title
FROM Game JOIN Purchase ON Game.GameID = Purchase.GameID
GROUP BY Game.Title
ORDER BY NumSold DESC ;
```

I want to save the GameID of the top row to a variable.

I have tried this, but can't seem to get the Game ID of the 'game' with the most 'purchase' rows. I can get the purchase row count of various games when I switch around the variables out of desperation.

```
SET @BestSellerID = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(Game.GameID) AS Best
                     FROM Game JOIN Purchase ON Game.GameID = Purchase.GameID
                     ORDER BY Best DESC
                     );
```

I have tried SELECT way too (INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR TOP):

```
DECLARE @BestSellerID int;

SELECT @BestSellerID = TOP 1 COUNT(Game.GameID) AS NumSold, Game.Title
FROM Game JOIN Purchase ON Game.GameID = Purchase.GameID
GROUP BY Game.Title
ORDER BY NumSold DESC ;
```

Is this not possible because there's no way to get scalar result? Can someone please explain to me how get a variable from the result set? Is there some concept I'm missing, is there a special way to 'talk to' queries after they have been er queried? Thank you.

OK with user tshoemake's help and fumbling with syntax this fixed my problem:

```
    DECLARE @BestSellerID int;

with cte_bs as 
(
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(Game.GameID) AS NumSold, Game.GameID
FROM Game JOIN Purchase ON Game.GameID = Purchase.GameID
GROUP BY Game.GameID
ORDER BY NumSold DESC
)
select @BestSellerID = (SELECT cte_bs.GameID FROM cte_bs)
select @BestSellerID AS BestSellerGameID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're selecting two element (GameID and Title).  I imagine it's looking for only one GameID to store in the local variable. This is a total shot in the dark without sample data, but try this or use this to get to where you need to be.

```
DECLARE @BestSellerID int;

with cte as 
(
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(Game.GameID) AS NumSold, Game.GameID
FROM Game JOIN Purchase ON Game.GameID = Purchase.GameID
GROUP BY Game.GameID
ORDER BY NumSold DESC
)
set @BestSellerID = select top 1 cte.GameID from cte 

select @BestSellerID
```

Comment: syntax error near 'top' But if change code to not assign: select top 1 cte.GameID from cte; I get the correct GameID! But it won't let me assign the variable

Comment: Try this: set @BestSellerID = select top 1 cte.GameID from cte.  I also made some changes to the original answer, you will want to include this as well.

Comment: Still get syntax errors from the semicolon after DESC and setting the var, is there different syntax for cte expressions?

Comment: My snytax at a glance seems ok on the cte, take out the semicolon (copied this in from your original code :D) @MrPickles7

Comment: I tried column names in the cte, still tells me there is syntax error by set, what could this possibly mean?

Comment: select @BestSellerID = (SELECT cte.GameID FROM cte_bs) Works! Thanks tshoemake, you HAVE to use CTEs for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ResultQuery inorder to store it to a local variable in java with Mysql database

My code suggestions is :

```
 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) AS NumSold, Game.Title,Game.GameID
    FROM Game JOIN Purchase ON Game.GameID = Purchase.GameID
    GROUP BY Game.Title
    ORDER BY NumSold DESC ;");
    if(rs.next())
    int GameID=rs.getInt("Game.GameID");

//You can use a array if you want to store large set of numbers
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trapped inside sql-server